# WordPress user account activation

Tags: plugins, filters, actions, activation

How do I implement user account activation in WordPress? (This is not for multisite.)

Once the user registers through the site or admin panel, the user should get an email with an activation link.

Once the link is opened the account should be activated and should be redirected to the login page. Also need to check the account is activated or not in login.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [Profile Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder) provides all those features.

From the WordPress plugin repository readme:

> Profile Builder is WordPress user registration done right.

And from the [creator's website](https://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/#features):

> **Admin Approval for new users**
>
> You decide who is a user on your website. Get notified via email or approve multiple users at once from the WordPress UI.